# JSP is not loading the jdbc driver

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have my LoadDriver class which is working as intended (no error)

```
package p_test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoadDriver {   
    public static void Load() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have my jsp file

```
<%@ page import="p_test.LoadDriver"%>

<% LoadDriver.Load(); %>
```

When i run it he cant find the driver

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1320)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at p_test.LoadDriver.Load(LoadDriver.java:16)
```

I am using tomcat 8.0.
I just started with jsp so i dont know where the program searches the driver!

And if someone can recommend a good JSP Book or an online tutorial that would be great.

Comment: Is the driver jar present in classpath?

Comment: if you use eclipse then press _ctrl_ + _shift_ + _t_ and type **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** see if matching items shows or not??

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the MySQL JDBC connector in your classpath. You can place the Jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your project.

Or you can place it under `CATALINA_HOME/lib` to be available for all your applications where `CATALINA_HOME` is an environment variable pointing to the root of your Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have MySql driver in your classpath. You have to place mysql connector jar inside WEB-INF/lib folder of your app

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mysql driver to your project lib. You will find driver jar file here [MYSQL DRIVER](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)

You can refer this link [JSP MYSQL EXAMPLE](http://www.9lessons.info/2008/09/jsp-login-page-to-connect-mysql-atabase.html) for better understanding.

Welcome to JSP World :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server yor are using has MySql driver.